# Loop through time period to get weeks

Tags: c#, iterator, timespan

If I have a list of appointments and like to get those in a weeks instead in a loop eg.

```
public class appointments
{
     public string Appointment { get; set; }
     public DateTime Start { get; set; }
     public string Location { get; set; }
}

List<appointments> appointment = new List<appointments>();

appointment.Add(new appointments() { Appointment = "meeting", Start = new DateTime(2013, 01,02), Location = "office"});
appointment.Add(new appointments() { Appointment = "lunch",  Start = new DateTime(2013, 01, 07), Location = "cafe" });
appointment.Add(new appointments() { Appointment = "meeting", Start = new DateTime(2013, 01, 08), Location = "cityhall" });
appointment.Add(new appointments() { Appointment = "dentist", Start = new DateTime(2013, 01, 14), Location = "dentist" });
```

Now I want a timeperiod from say `2013-01-02` to `2013-01-25`, and the startdate 01-02 are going to be the start week.

So the items between 02 to 08 is one week 09-16 another and so on till the end that doesent have 7 days in its week. how can I it iterate the list and pass just specific weeks to another method without pre calculate the "weeks brake date" just adding 7 days until the end?

Comment: do weeks start on certain day, like Monday or Sunday? Or, do you just want to iterate in chunks of 7 days?

Answer (score 1):

The code below returns "dentist" for week 1 and "meeting,lunch,meeting" for week 0.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<appointments> appointment = new List<appointments>();

        appointment.Add(new appointments() { Appointment = "meeting", Start = new DateTime(2013, 01, 02), Location = "office" });
        appointment.Add(new appointments() { Appointment = "lunch", Start = new DateTime(2013, 01, 07), Location = "cafe" });
        appointment.Add(new appointments() { Appointment = "meeting", Start = new DateTime(2013, 01, 08), Location = "cityhall" });
        appointment.Add(new appointments() { Appointment = "dentist", Start = new DateTime(2013, 01, 14), Location = "dentist" });

        foreach (var appt in GetAppointmentsByWeek(appointment, 1))
            Console.WriteLine(appt.Appointment);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<appointments> GetAppointmentsByWeek(List<appointments> appts, int weeknum)
    {
        if (weeknum < 0)
            return new appointments[] { };

        var ordered = appts.OrderBy(a => a.Start.Ticks);           
        var start = ordered.First().Start.AddDays(weeknum * 7);
        var end = start.AddDays(7);
        return ordered.Where(o => o.Start.Ticks >= start.Ticks && o.Start.Ticks <= end.Ticks);
    }
}

public class appointments
{
    public string Appointment { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `GroupBy` on the appointments to group them by the specific week. This code is untested and freehanded but you should get the idea.

```
private static IEnumerable<appointments> GetAppointmentsByWeek(List<appointments> appts, int weeknum)
{
    var WeekGroup = appts.GroupBy(ap => GetWeekOfYear(ap.Start)).Where(gp => gp.Key == weeknum).FirstOrDefault();

    if (WeekGroup == null) {return new List<appointments>();} //No appointments for this week

    return WeekGroup.Select(gp => gp.ToList());
}
```

You'll need to implement `GetWeekOfYear` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx ) - but this for any given list of appointments and a given week number will return all of the appointments in that week.